# LINQ with group by for nested list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to filter and get a list if my main object using Linq with my nested lists.
what I require is - `List<Category>`

```
class Category contains List<Order> and List<Price>
```

[image]

But the result i get is grouped by both the child objects, hence i dont get the exact result. I want to group this seperatly to get the result. Below is my Linq query,

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var resultList = (
    from category in Connection.Table<Category>().ToList()
    join order in Connection.Table<Order>().ToList()
        on category.Id equals order.CategoryId
    join price in Connection.Table<Price>().ToList()
        on category.Id equals price.CategoryId
    where category.Id == TestID
    select new {
        category.ID,
        category.Name,
        order,
        price
    } into grou
    group grou by new {
        grou.Id
    } into grp
    select new Category {
        Id = grp.Id,
        Order = grp.Select(x => x.order).ToList(),
        Price = grp.Select(x => x.price).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: You better explain this by showing sample data (input/output), or ideally an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't understand your description.

Comment: hi Gert, I have added more details. kindly help.

Comment: *class Category contains List<Order> and List<Price>*. So just list your categories with these collections included by `Include`.

Comment: Can you please state with an example, i am not familiar with Linq

Comment: I think you're not using Entity Framework but LINQ-to-SQL (seeing the `Table<T>` calls). Could you show the `Connection` class?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.  At least one case you had ID instead of Id :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

         }
    }
    public class cConnection
    {
        public cConnection Connection { get; set; }

        public List<cTable<Entity>> Table<Entiry>() { return null; } 

        public void Test()
        {
            int TestID = 123;

            var resultList = (from mainObjectEntity in Connection.Table<MainObjectEntity>().ToList()
                    join child1Entity in Connection.Table<Child1Entity>().ToList()
                    on mainObjectEntity.Id equals child1Entity.MainObjectEntityId
                    join child2Entity in Connection.Table<Child2Entity>().ToList()
                    on mainObjectEntity.Id equals child2Entity.MainObjectEntityId
                    where mainObjectEntity.TestId == TestID
                    select new
                    {
                        id = mainObjectEntity.TestId,
                        mainObjectEntity = mainObjectEntity,
                        child1 = child1Entity,
                        child2 = child2Entity
                    })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.id)
                    .Select(grp => new {
                        TestID = grp.FirstOrDefault().id,
                        Child1Entity = grp.Select(x => x.child1).ToList(),
                        Child2Entity = grp.Select(x => x.child2).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class cTable<T> : Entity
    {
        public int MainObjectEntityId { get; set; }
        public int TestId { get; set; }
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child1Entity : Entity
    {

    }
    public class Child2Entity : Entity
    {
    }
    public class MainObjectEntity : Entity
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply jdweng. 

but the above query doen't help me, as it would give me consolidated number of rows for both the child entities.

Comment: Look at code again.  The code produces two lists.  One for each child.